# getting user input and add to the sqlite flutter

Tags: flutter, sqlite

Please someone help me, I have a textfileds and textfields controller. There additional textfield can be added by user so i created list of textController and other usual controller(not a list). Now i want add user input to sql lite datebase for saving and getting it. I dont know how to get user input to the sqlite. I only get input by usual controller(not a list). Get by controller.text, but list of controller dont have dot text property.

```
final titleController = TextEditingController();// this i know how to get titleconroller.text
  final _instructionsController = TextEditingController();
  final _timeController = TextEditingController();
  final _portionController = TextEditingController();
  final List<TextEditingController> _ingredientsController = []; // but TYPE of List dont have dot text to get value
  final List<TextEditingController> stepsController = [];
  final List<TextEditingController> _quaController = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to get the index of the controller in the list then get the .text from that.

```
_ingredientsController[i].text
```

Comment: Yes but i dont know how in my case